# Oracle APEX - Retrieve data from JSON object and set it to Color Picker

Tags: oracle-apex

An user can pick colors in this setting page:

[image]

And I store the color code as JSON object like this:

```
{"attention": #fd1313, "property": #ea00ff, "not_reported": #0004ff, "off_property": #00ffe1, "carts_in_use": #1eff00, "carts_idle": #ffd500}
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the stored color code and display them in the setting page everytime the user open the page.
I thought I can achieve this by setting SQL query in Source section like this (setting_pref is the column name, USR is the table name) :

[image]

[image]

However, it doesn't display the color code.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you want to show this - in a separate page item or in the existing page item ? That source screenshot you're displaying - what page item is it the source of ?

Comment: I want to display it in the existing page - setting page (the 1st pic in the question) and the source screenshot is "Carts idle in store" page item (which is Color Picker). I added another screenshot

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid json - validate it in any json validator. The hex values should be in quotes.

Comment: I added " " to the color code in json and now it's working! Thank you very much for your help (again)